# Deep Linking Issue - Opening in Web Browser Instead of App

Tags: deep-linking

**Description:**

I'm encountering an issue with deep linking in my React application using Capacitor. Despite implementing the necessary code, when I click a URL on my mobile, it opens in the web browser instead of my app.

Details:

I have followed the guide at [Capacitor Deep Links](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links) and implemented the following code in a component named `AppUrlListener:`

```
const AppUrlListener: React.FC<any> = () => {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect");
    App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (event: URLOpenListenerEvent) => {
      // const  url  = "https://example.app/cellar/profile"
      // const slag = "/cellar/profile";
      const slug = event.url.split('.app').pop();
      console.log("slug: " + slug);
      if (slug) {
        navigate(slug);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default AppUrlListener;
```

In my `app.tsx,` I call this component within a `BrowserRouter:`

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <AppUrlListener></AppUrlListener>
  {/* Other components */}
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Additional Information:**

On Google Digital Assets, I have confirmed the hosting, package name, and App package fingerprint. My `AndroidManifest.xml` includes the necessary intent filters:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.app" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, the URLs I click on mobile are still opening in the web browser instead of the app.

**Question:**

What could be causing this behavior, and how can I ensure that the deep links open in my app rather than the web browser?

I was expecting URL link  to open the app and not on the web.

Note that the app has not launched yet.